# How to determine boundary of a $3D$ Klein bottle?

Tags: klein-bottle

A question struggled me for a long time: If a $3D$ Klein Bottle represented by Robert Israel function. How to determine the exact boundary. I mean if you put it in a cuboid, what will the exact values of width, length, and height of the cuboid be?

$$\begin{align}
x(u,v) =& -\frac{2}{15}\cos u(3\cos v - 30\sin u + 90 \cos^4 u\sin u\\
& - 60\cos^6 u \sin u + 5\cos u \cos v\sin u)\\
y(u,v) =& -\frac{1}{15}\sin u(3\cos v - 3\cos^2 u\cos v - 48\cos^4 u\cos v + 48\cos^6 u \cos v\\
&-60\sin u + 5\cos u\cos v\sin u - 5\cos^3 u\cos v\sin u \\
&-80\cos^5 u\cos v\sin u + 80\cos^7u \cos v \sin u )\\
z(u,v) =& \frac{2}{15}(3 + 5\cos u\sin u)\sin v
\end{align}
$$
for $0 \le u < \pi$ and $0 \le v < 2\pi$.

original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM00U.png

Comment: Your attempt to post a link didn't work. Perhaps you can type out Robert's description of that "Klein bottle."

Comment: @DragonZ What do you mean? Explain please better about that we say.

Comment: The $z$-variable is pretty easy to handle. $5\cos u\sin u=(5/2)\sin2u$ lies between $-5/2$ and $5/2$, so $z$ lies between $-11/15$ (when $u=\pi/4$ and $v=3\pi/2$) and $11/15$ (when $u=\pi/4$ and $v=\pi/2$). The others look like they might get messy, once you've taken the partial derivatives and set them equal to zero and tried to solve for $u$ and $v$, but one can anyway make trivial estimates just based on $|\sin t|\le1$ and $|\cos t|\le1$: $|x|\le388/15$, $|y|\le332/15$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, I may try your boundary in my program to see whether it has any error. I really haven't touch Calculus for a long time and need to review for how to determine the boundary

Comment: @GerryMyerson Are you certain about the range is so large? The z-variable ranges 22/15=1.467 (from -11/15 to 11/15) which is easy to be determined and the range of x variable and y variable of your estimation seems too large. I tested in my program, the range of x should be about 3.712 and the range of y should be about 4.4, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I never said the range was that large. I said those were trivial estimates on how large the range is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Then that is really a large estimation. Any idea of calculate it in accurate way?

Comment: As I wrote earlier, you can take partial derivatives, set them equal to zero, and try to solve. If you can't solve by hand, there are computer algebra programs like Maple and Mathematica and Matlab that might be able to solve for you. Maybe Wolfram Alpha can handle it.

Comment: Making any progress with those partial derivatives?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I need to review Calculus first, that's why I determine myself as a Programmer, not a mathematic researcher.

Comment: OK. Take your time. Keep us informed.